# Finger-print reader no more working

Tags: fingerprint

I have an HP ProBook 4430s with a fingerprint reader. I had to reinstall my OS a few days back. Since then, I don't see any sign of my fingerprint reader. I installed HP Security tools, I installed the fingerprint reader drivers from the HP website... but still, it's not working.

The windows control panel's 'biometric devices' also doesn't show any sign of the fingerprint reader.

Comment: If the device is not listed in device manager thent he required drivers are not installed.  Specific information about the device, and os, and drivers you installed are required to help

Comment: The device is built-in Fingerprint reader of HP ProBook4430s, OS: Windows 7 Ultimate (x64), Drivers downloaded from HP website,
The driver is... 'HP Validity Fingerprint sensor driver (x64)'...
Well it shows as 'Validity Sensor' on Device Manager, but I see no way to activate the fingerprint reader...